# Wrong Merchant Type From Magento

Tags: magento, authorize.net

I have set up payment processing through Authorize.net (actually through a reseller) and I am able to successfully perform Test transactions.  However, when I perform real transactions, I get a Rejected transaction.  When I check the transaction in the authorize.net account I see "General Error (Request rejected by FDC Omaha - Wrong Merchant Type).  I assume this is some sort of configuration problem between First Data and authorize.net or me.  However, I have no way of telling exactly what the problem is.  Authorize.net told me to contact my MSP and the reseller is saying there is nothing they can do to fix the problem (I find it hard to believe.)  Is this a setting on my side that I can fix? Help!

Answer (score 0):

You must contact your merchant account provider to fix this error. I've seen this error message several times with our customers at www.authnetscripts.com.

The error indicates a mis-configuration with the processor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We got this error recently on one of our sites, so we followed the advice to call the merchant account provider.

We called and they told us that sometimes you can get this error because of the type of card (MasterCard, Visa, Discover, AmEx, etc.) that is being used. We tried a different type of card and it processed correctly.

Hopefully that helps someone else who runs into this same problem.